# How to use third-party libraries in Azure IoT SDK for C?

Tags: c, xcode, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have set up the Azure IoT Hub SDK for C on macOS (10.15.3) and can successfully build and run the samples from within Xcode (11.3.1).

If I try to include third-party libraries like libmodbus, I have to specify the full path like this: `#include "/usr/local/include/modbus/modbus.h"` Otherwise it cannot be found.

If I write my code outside of the azure-iot-sdk-c directory, I have the reverse problem: All the third-party libraries installed on my system are found, but none of the Azure IoT SDK libraries can be found.

Also, if I include the full path to a third-party library, it is found but I still can't use it as Xcode is giving me the following error and four more similar ones:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_modbus_close", referenced from:
      _readModbus in iothub_convenience_sample.o
```

So, how do you actually use the Azure IoT SDK for C to develop your own applications?

All the official documentation and tutorials only tell you how to build and run the samples. How do you go beyond that? How can you use the SDK libraries together with third-party libraries in your own code?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem of yours except that I'm on Linux...